# How to know the width of a specific character in specific font styles?

Tags: fonts, ms-word, typesetting

How can i know the width of a specific character in specific font styles?

For example: in font "Arial", a letter "p" with Bold, underline, 28px font size, how can i know the width of this letter?

I mean I want to get the width in server side, which means I don't have a browser environment, I need the process of this calculate is very fast.

I just want to implement a **Typesetting Engine** such as the ms-word did.

Comment: Better question: why? What are you trying to _do_ that you think requires knowing the width of individual letters?

Comment: I want to implement a Typesetting Engine such as the ms-word did.
So I need to know the width of individual letters that I can know where to break the line.

Comment: Good luck with that. The only answer for someone who's actually writing a full typesetting engine (outside of: "don't reinvent the wheel, use already available engines like FreeType2 for text shaping, and help improve those instead) is to learn about how text metrics and font shaping works at the font level. You'll have to read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/ and learn how fonts store that information.